# Android app RelativeLayout not showing

Tags: android-layout

so im trying to use a relative layout (for basic app tabs at the bottom of the screen) and it is not showing when i place it inside the LinearLayout after 2 other layouts (a LinearLayout and a ScrollView). The ScrollView contains several textViews and scrolls nicely on its own and the linearlayout before it also works nicely, but the relativelayout that i have tried to place at the bottom of the screen does not work.
Here is the general code for what i am trying to do:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/common_bg"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <TextView android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Heading"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_gravity="top" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

           <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

           <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:textColor="@color/white"
                         android:textSize="18dp"
                         android:textStyle="bold"
                         android:text="@string/text"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           </TextView>


           </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE: the Relative layout that im using is custom in a way that i cant actually show the code for it here, but it contains a radio group with several buttons.

UPDATE 2: Ok, so I solved the problem by manipulating the layout_height="wrap_content" on the 3 layouts (the first linear, the one holding the scroller, and the bottom relativelayout) as well as manipulating the layout_wieght of each of them until I was satisfied with the way it looked... it doesnt seem like this is the best possible solution, but it worked so i cant complain too much lol...

Answer (score 0):

The relative layout in itself wont be displayed in an xml graphical layout or when you are running the app, it needs a child element to occupy the parent layout, try putting a text view inside the relative layout, it'll be displayed, position it right below the linear layout having the scroll view, it'll work properly, i just tried it with your code and it works

Comment: it still doesnt work. I even redundantly have the scrollview contained within a linearview, yet the bottomMenu that i have as the relativeview still wont appear. I have eclipse showing me the graphical view but that shows me that the bottomMenu is below the screen as if the scrollview takes up all of the screen and shoves out anything else. Now that relativeview bottomMenu DOES appear when i try to put it into the scrollview, it just appears at the bottom of the scrolling linearlayout... Any ideas how i can fix this?